# Why are the colors lighter in the flash application?

Tags: image, apache-flex, background

When I specify either the backgroundColor of my application, or an element of the application (any kind), or I set the application background image with

```
<s:BitmapImage left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" fillMode="repeat" source="assets/bg1.png"/>
```

, I always get lighter colors than what I specify with hex code or the background image / or solid color.

Here is the example screenshot of the background of my application, that I see in the browser:

[image: Browser]

Here is the example screenshot of the original image editor with the image, that I save to the source folder:

[image: Pixelmator]

**The original image is clearly darker and more vivid than what is displayed in the browser.**

- I cleared the project, cleared the cache, tried both Firefox and
  Chrome, all the same.
- The application alpha is set to one.
- The embedded swf does not have any css-based alpha property.
- I tried to load the pure swf to the browser, all the same.
- I am using Flash Builder 4.6.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: It might have to do with color profiles. What's the "image editor" that you use? What's the color profile of your original image? How do export your PNG file?

Comment: Anything floating on top of the BitMapImage could change the color.  IS there any reason you don't specify a backgroundColor on the Application tag to give your app a background color?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#styleSummary

Comment: Make sure that your image is displayed without any scaling in both cases. Also try to open your image in browser, not in editor, and then to compare with swf in browser.

Comment: Image editor: Pixelmator on Mac
Nothing is floating there, no top elements.
I also tried to specify the backgroundColor on my application, al the same, the displayed color is paler than it should be.
I opened the image in the browser, it is okay there, ...but the solidColors in the swf are paler too, so there might be something with the swf, not the image :(